# test if vertical line intersects another

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm testing if two line segments intersect (given the coordinates of the endpoints).

First I calculate the function for each line

```
y = ax + b
```

My question is: what to do if one of the lines is vertical (i.e. a = infinity)?

I know I can rotate the two lines, but is there another, easier solution?

Comment: I think you can put this as an answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the other one is not also vertical, then your x-coordinate is done. now subs this in non vertical line and get the y-coordinate.